# Get single record from Inner Joins SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android programming. I am having a little issue on how to retrieve a single record while using Inner joins. From research I know how to do it with one table e.g

```
public Shop getShop(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SHOPS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
KEY_NAME, KEY_SH_ADDR }, KEY_ID + "=?",
new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
cursor.moveToFirst();
Shop contact = new Shop(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
// return shop
return contact;
}
```

But I am at a loss when I have to consider three different tables. I have been able to retrieve all records, currently my code to retreive a single record is below. I have been able to replace `?` with a corresponding `id` and it works but I obviously do not want to have that static.

### getTeam method

```
//Getting Single Team
public List < Team > getTeam() {
 List < Team > teamList = new ArrayList < Team > ();
 // Select All Query
 String selectQuery = "SELECT teams.id, teams.team_name, teams.image, teams_vs_leagues.points, leagues.league_name " +
  "FROM teams_vs_leagues " +
  "INNER JOIN teams " +
  "ON teams_vs_leagues.team_id = teams.id " +
  "INNER JOIN leagues " +
  "ON teams_vs_leagues.league_id = leagues.id " +
  "WHERE teams.id = ?";

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
 // looping through all rows and adding to list
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
   Team team = new Team();
   team.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
   team.setTeamName(cursor.getString(1));
   team.setPath(cursor.getString(2));
   team.setPoints(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
   team.setLeagueName(cursor.getString(4));
   // Adding team to list
   teamList.add(team);
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
 // close inserting data from database
 db.close();
 // return team list
 return teamList;

}
```

### Team class

```
public class Team {
 String team_name, path, league_name;
 int id, league_id, points;

 public Team(int keyId, String team_name, String path,
  int points, String league_name) {
  this.id = keyId;
  this.team_name = team_name;
  this.path = path;
  this.points = points;
  this.league_name = league_name;
 }

 public Team() {}

 public Team(int keyId) {
  this.id = keyId;

 }

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int keyId) {
  this.id = keyId;
 }


 public int getLeagueId() {
  return league_id;
 }


 public String getTeamName() {
  return team_name;
 }

 public String getLeagueName() {
  return league_name;
 }

 public void setLeagueName(String league_name) {
  this.league_name = league_name;
 }

 public int getPoints() {
  return points;
 }

 public void setPoints(int points) {
  this.points = points;
 }


 public void setTeamName(String team_name) {
  this.team_name = team_name;
 }

 public void setLeague_id(int league_id) {
  this.league_id = league_id;
 }

 public void setPath(String path) {
  this.path = path;
 }

 public String getPath() {
  return path;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using placeholder

```
"WHERE teams.id = ?";
```

in your query , you need to pass selection arguments in `rawQuery()` so that during the execution of your query , the placeholder will be replaced by the actual value.

`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{id});`//"id" is the value which you want to pass in place of "?". You can hardcode it or you can pass it all the way to  `getTeam()`

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) .